# Share an image, text and link to Facebook iOS 11 Swift 4

Tags: swift4, ios11, facebook-share

I'm trying to share a content which contains an imageURL, text and a link from my app (which will eventually be an App Link) to Facebook.
I tried using Social Framework but it seems like Facebook and Twitter are deprecated.

I tried FacebookShare:

```
let content = LinkShareContent(url: url! , title: "some title, description: "some description", quote: "", imageURL: imgURL as URL?)
```

And its also deprecated.

I also tried **FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject** (Facebook API v3.1) like this:

```
let iosURLS = ["al:ios:url":"deeplink://","al:ios:app_name": "xxx",
                   "al:ios:app_store_id": "123456"]
    let imageURL = "some url"
    let properties: NSDictionary =  [
                    "fb:app_id": "xxxxxxx",
                    "og:type": "article",
                    "al:ios": iosURLS,
                    "og:url": "some link",
                    "og:title": "a title",
                    "og:image": imageURL,
                    "og:description": "a description"
                ]
    let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties as! [AnyHashable : Any])
    let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
    action.actionType = "news.publishes"
    action.setObject(object, forKey: "article")
    let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
    content.action = action
    content.previewPropertyName = "article"

    FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

The sharing works fine but the app link doesn't.